# Passing String Between Two Classes Is Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I am working with Google's Places API for iOS, and I need to pass a string from one of the classes (GooglePlacesConnection) to GooglePlacesObject.

Here, in the first class, I set distanceMatrixURL equal to the string timeURL

```
 timeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%f,%f&destinations=%@,%@&sensor=true",userLat,userLng,destLat,destLng];

                GooglePlacesObject *googleplacesobject = [[GooglePlacesObject alloc]init];

                googleplacesobject.distanceMatrixURL = timeURL;
                NSLog(@"pullurl is %@",  googleplacesobject.distanceMatrixURL);
```

and the NSLog prints out googleplacesobject.distanceMatrixURL correctly.
However, in the second class, when I do

```
-(void)distanceMatrix{

NSLog(@"%@",distanceMatrixURL);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:distanceMatrixURL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];


_connection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[_connection2 start];
if (_connection2)
{
    responseData2 = [NSMutableData data];
    connectionIsActive = YES;
    NSLog(@"connection is active with %@", responseData2);
} else {
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
}
```

the NSLog of NSLog(@"%@",distanceMatrixURL); is (null)

Comment: Sorry probably I did not understand, but, where is in order : defined set distanceMatrixURL??

Comment: it is defined in the .h files
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString   *distanceMatrixURL;

Comment: ok but where you assign something to this string?

Comment: when i do  googleplacesobject.distanceMatrixURL = timeURL;
in the other class

Comment: And how the other class knows this object : googleplacesobject ?? Because the title of your question is how to pass string between two classes is not  working properly, but where do you pass this string?

Comment: GooglePlacesObject *googleplacesobject = [[GooglePlacesObject alloc]init]; googleplacesobject.distanceMatrixURL = timeURL;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31616/discussion-between-elio-d-and-alexyuiop)

Comment: from where you are calling distanceMatrix method?